# For loop returning odd values

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, append

I have two lists I want to iterate through:

```
efw = [13.882352941176457, 10.854092526690406, 94.25675675675676, 17.851739788199694, 14.63844797178131, 8.166189111747846, 5.278592375366564, 3.4129692832764347, -6.413612565445015, 11.678832116788328, 23.859649122807003, 4.545454545454564, 10.105580693815996, -3.562340966921118, -0.6684491978609763, 2.285714285714291, 8.505747126436791]
```

and

```
gini = [3.9215686274509887, 6.190476190476191, -7.733812949640296, -16.608391608391603, -13.458262350936979, 7.505518763796926, -12.884615384615394, -20.21276595744681, -19.839679358717433, -10.885608856088568, -12.891986062717764, -15.56420233463035, -12.66540642722116, -12.802768166089962, -11.336032388663975, -13.507625272331147, -1.882845188284521]
```

I want to create two new lists with `+` and `-` depending on the values in `gini` and `efw`. If the value in `gini` is positive, then a `+` should be added to the `g` list. Same with the `e` and `efw` lists. I have tried:

```
g = []
e = []
for n in gini:
    if n > 0:
        g.append("+")
    g.append("-")

for f in efw:
    if f > 0:
        e.append("+")
    e.append("-")
```

But for some positive values in `gini` there is a `-` sign... Why is the for loop appending the wrong symbols to the new lists?

Comment: didn't you need to add else in your condition? every value in your array will appended with '-' with your current code

Comment: Yes! Adding `elif` solved it!

Answer (score 2):

Adding `else` solved it.

```
g = []
e = []
for n in gini:
    if n > 0:
        g.append("+")
    else:
        g.append("-")


for f in efw:
    if f > 0:
        e.append("+")
    else:
        e.append("-")
```

Comment: why use `elif`? you should just use `else` and get rid of the `pass` statements.

Comment: using the `continue` statement can also simplify the code

Comment: Better still you can do it with a list comprehension: `["+" if i>0 else "-" for i in gini]`

Comment: If one of the elements is `0`, your code will add '-' sign for it. Shouldn't you have a case for that?